# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. - cshtml?

Tags: .net, razor, pdf-generation

any ideas why this is not working? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
 <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Suma netto</th>
              <th scope="col">Suma VAT</th>
              <th scope="col">Suma brutto</th> 
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            @{
                var totalNetto = 0;
                var totalVat = 0;
                var totalBrutto = 0;

                @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++){
                var position = Model.Data[i];
                 i = i + 1;
                 totalNetto = totalNetto + Convert.ToInt32(@position.NetPrice);
                 totalVat = totalVat + Convert.ToInt32(@position.TaxRate);
                 totalBrutto = totalBrutto + Convert.ToInt32(@position.BruttoPrice);
                
            }
              <tr>
              <td>@totalNetto</td>
              <td>@totalVat</td>
              <td>@totalBrutto</td>   
            </tr>
           }
          </tbody>
    </table>
```

My @position.NetPrice, @position.TaxRate, @position.BruttoPrice are strings

Network response error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Management_TransactionReport.<ExecuteAsync>b__8_1() in C:\Users\ncichewicz\Desktop\GapMap\BackEnd\API\Views\Management\TransactionReport.cshtml:line 74
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Management_TransactionReport.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.ViewAsPdf.CallTheDriver(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.BuildFile(ActionContext context)
   at Rotativa.AspNetCore.AsResultBase.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Logic - I've a list of models and need to sum TaxRate, NetPrice and BruttoPrice

Also if there is a shorter and better way to do it just tell me :)

Comment: This error can be thrown if it is not able to convert input when calling Covert.ToInt32. So please check if Convert.ToInt32() is trying to convert a valid data into int.

Comment: I use the same data above and it's working fine as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get an error if one of the @position.NetPrice, @position.TaxRate, @position.BruttoPrice values is a decimal

Comment: all of these values are strings

Comment: If the string is in decimal format, it cannot convert it like "15.5". You can check the examples in the link.  https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-6.0#code-try-2